Very bad distortion in Pod Studio GX Audio
I'm running Pop!_OS. I just downloaded and installed it in the past week, so latest version.
Sometimes the audio from my Pod Studio GX (USB Audio, basically) is very distorted. I don't see a pattern as to what's triggering it. It just seems kind of random. As part of the distortion, the audio plays very slowly. Like it's playing 1/4 speed, maybe?
The fix is simple: If I open the "Sound" panel in Settings, it fixes the distortion. Just bringing up the sound settings itself. I don't have to change anything. So I assume it's performing some sort of reset either intentionally or in the act of querying the device.
Why is this happening? And how do I make it so it just doesn't get messed up in the first place?
The system doesn't start up that way. When I first boot the system, the audio in the Pod GX is fine.
